# Cross Browser alignment issue with select object

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-9, alignment

I have been agonizing over this, the alignment of my third table row is complete messed when viewed either Firefox or Chrome but look exactly as expected in IE9.
I have tried using style (text-align, width, margin-left, overflow, etc...) and direct align, width. etc.... When creating the width, I have tried using % and direct pixel values.

The parent table has a width 400px, or at least is should because that is the width of the parent TD and table width is 100% and cellpadding and cellspacing is 0.

```
<table align="center" style="width: 650px; border-style: none" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 250px;"><img src="../images/incidentmonitor.gif" alt="" /></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 400px">
<!-- Login section Table -->

            <table align="center" style="width: 100%; border-style: none;" class="clsLoginTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; width: 25%; overflow: hidden;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; width: 5%; overflow: hidden;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="text-align: left; width: 70%; overflow: hidden;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="clsLoginLabel" style="text-align:center;">
                        <p><b>Please enter your User ID and Password</b><br /><br /></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right;" class="clsLoginLabel">User ID:</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="text-align: left;"><input name="UserID" value="administrator" size="20" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right;" class="clsLoginLabel">Password:</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="text-align: left;"><input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="Password" onkeydown="SendForm(event.keyCode)" size="20" /></td>
                </tr>


                <tr style="display: block;">
                    <td align="right" width="25%" class="clsLoginLabel">Domain:</td>
                    <td align="right" width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left" width="70%">
                        <select id="DomainName" name="DomainName" size="1" style="width: 200px">

                            <option selected="selected" value='' >Built-In</option>

                            <option value='dnsdev.com' >dnsdev.com</option>

                            <option value='dnsdev.org' >dnsdev.org</option>

                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">
                        <button id="submit_request" name="submit_request" class="clsButton" accesskey="L" onclick="Validate();return false" Title="Login to IncidentMonitor "><u>L</u>ogin</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Using tables for layouts went out of practice many years ago.

Comment: I love a high an mighty response without any details. That being said, the alignment is being broken by the style="display: block" on the table row. Any insights as to the reason for this?

Comment: Once I identified the that the table row style was the issue have fixed the alignment issue by using div wrapper.